# Displaying html data in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have in my database a column that stores html data i.e `<p>this is a test</p>` and I am loading that data into a javascript form field, however, the html tags are not being parsed properly.

They are being displayed such as;

```
&lt;p&gt;This is a test&lt;/p&gt;
```

Can someone give me a hint as to what I am doing wrong please.

Comment: Which language your using for database operation?

Comment: How are they stored in the database? Check the database first so we can understand if there is an issue with the way data is stored or with the way it is displayed.

Comment: @SmartDev they are stored like `<p>this is a test</p>` which is fine, is when its being fetched and displayed.

Comment: @J.D did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your text using `.html` function

```
var text= $('<textarea />').html("&lt;p&gt;This is a test&lt;/p&gt").text();
alert(text);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/atate143/npe5d74h/)**

Comment: Its just parsing the result in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the tags are being saved as their HTML entity equivalent. You'll have to convert them to their actual character if that's what you require.